# Delineate polygonal catchment areas from a raster using open-source GIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, open-source-gis

I'm 90% sure this basic question has been asked before but looking through the other posts I simply do not see a useful answer.

I need to calculate polygonal(vector) catchment areas from a raster based on minimum driving distance/cost from a set of points. I've already got the raster, and for that matter, the nodes(intersections with cost attribute) used to interpolate it. What I need now are polygons for each point describing the area nearer it than any other point. This is basically like a voronoi diagram but based on network distance rather than euclidean space.

How exactly can I do this using only open-source tools? I'm comfortable with the command line if I just know what I'm looking for. I feel like GDAL is going to be the answer, but if so, what exactly is the command I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- GRASS GIS (an GRASS GIS from QGIS): [Vector aggregate values](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_aggregate_values)
- SAGA GIS from QGIS: [Some hydrological analysis](http://qgissextante.blogspot.be/2012/11/some-hydrological-analysis.html)
- PostGIS from QGIS: [Creating Catchment Areas with pgRouting and QGIS](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/09/creating-catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-and-qgis/) (Underdark)